# How to generate in R datetime variable from millisecond starting from precise datetime

Tags: r, lubridate

I have to convert a data frame with millisecond variable to a df with datetime variable (starting from a precise datetime) where milliseconds are progressively added to the previous datetime.**

In Excel is pretty straigthforward, I solved this way:

1) convert RR_ms in text with millisecond format "YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.xxx" (i.e. "0000-00-00 00:00:00.xxx")

2) add first millisecond to "2019-05-04 08:57:42.000"

3) add progressively other millisecond cells to previous cells

4) read the xlsx file into R (readxl, lubridate)

My aim to go from

```
head(sample[,1])
 A tibble: 6 x 1
  RR_ms
  <dbl>
1   789
2   789
3   796
4   792
5   769
6   753
```

to following df

```
head(sample[,1:2])
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  RR_ms   Time
  <dbl>   <datetime>
1  789    2019-05-04 08:57:42.789
2  789    2019-05-04 08:57:43.578
3  796    2019-05-04 08:57:44.374
4  792    2019-05-04 08:57:45.166
5  769    2019-05-04 08:57:45.935
6  753    2019-05-04 08:57:46.688
```

I would appreciate any tip or link as all I saw till now did not help me to produce the R code I need.

Best regards

Andrea

Comment: See `?as.POSIXct.numeric`, which has an `origin` option. `POSIXct` class stores timestamps as seconds-since-UTC epoch (Jan 1, 1970 UTC). So you'll have to convert the milliseconds to seconds first, but straightforward after that.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelChirico. I tried this conversion sample$sec <- as.POSIXct.numeric(sample$RR_ms/1000, origin = "2019-04-05 08:57:42") but I got wrong results (> head(sample$sec)
[1] "2019-04-05 10:57:42 CEST" "2019-04-05 10:57:42 CEST" "2019-04-05 10:57:42 CEST" "2019-04-05 10:57:42 CEST"
[5] "2019-04-05 10:57:42 CEST" "2019-04-05 10:57:42 CEST")

Comment: Look at `dput(head(sample$sec))`. Default printing method truncates sub-second values I think. Also try to supply `tz` argument to get the right time zone.

Comment: Solved with tz = "GMT". Thanks